# changed.jstree event not working in jstree inside of class method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am working on jstree checkbox plugin and I want to get the checked and unchecked state of the checkbox items. The changed.jstree event is not working in the _setEvents() method. But it is working fine when I add the event inside of _setTree() method. I need to get the event trigger in _setEvents() method.

This is the code I am using:

```
  export default class Test {
  constructor(container) {
    this._tab = null;
    this._container = container;
    this._setEvents();
  }

  get tab() {
    return this._tab;
  }  

  show(data) {
    this._data = data;   
    this._setTree();    

    return this;
  }  


  _setEvents() {
    const self = this;

    $(document)   

      .on('click', '#js-image-container', () => {
        $('#js-image-uploader').trigger('click');
      });
      $('#js-categories-container').on('changed.jstree', () => this._handleSelection());//this wont work

    return this;
  }


  _setTree() {
    $('#js-categories-container').jstree(jsonTreeGenerator.generate(this._data.categories));
    $('#js-categories-container').on('changed.jstree', () => this._handleSelection()); //this will work
    return this;
  }
  _handleSelection() {
   alert(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked for me - https://fiddle.jshell.net/ermakovnikolay/4b8ehrx8/. Are you sure you call this script after you have the html built and all the libs loaded? Can you see the tree at all?

Comment: There is an edit in my question, I have used a class and  2 methods. One method for the event and other one for triggering the jstree. I would like to trigger all the events inside of the _setEvents() method. I can't get into work.

Comment: Are you adding `js-categories-container` element dynamically?

Comment: Yes..The element creating from an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are adding the `js-categories-container` element dynamically, I believe it is not there yet at the time when you bind an event to it. So you have to delegate event handling, e.g. same way as you do for the `js-image-container` element. Check demo - [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/5zbnc0x4/):

```
$(document).on('click', '#js-image-container', 
    () => { $('#js-image-uploader').trigger('click'); }
);

$(document).on("click", '#js-categories-container', 
    () => {
       // get the node if you need it
       var node = $('#js-categories-container').jstree().get_node(event.target); 
       // do something
       this._handleSelection();
    }
);
```

Comment: I have added $(document).on('changed.jstree', '#js-categories-container', 
    () => { this._handleSelection(); }
); inside of the  _setEvents() method. But it is not working for me.

Comment: Sure, glad it helped!